# running python script on individual frames from client video feed

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets

I have a python program to analyze an image to detect a card, and it returns a url for the card's reference image. I want to host this program on a server so that any client can remote into the server, and have the script run on their video feed, displaying the resulting image from the python code. I am having issues extracting a single frame from the video feed and passing that as an argument to the python script. I have tried using pythonshell to pass in the frames, but the video stream is hosted within script.js and I want to run the python program in server.js

The python program is named 'card_detection.py' and is within the same directory. It would preferably take an opencv mat image as an argument.

If I could get the video feed from script.js, then is it possible to put the following code in server.js to run card_detection.py?

```
let options = { 
        mode: 'text', 
        pythonOptions: ['-u'], 
        args: [image] 
    }; 
      
  
    PythonShell.run('card_detector.py', options, function (err, result){ 
          if (err) throw err; 
          console.log('result: ', result.toString()); 
          io.emit(result.toString()) 
    });
```

Any help is appreciated! I have no experience with JS or HTML, my apologies.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')
const {PythonShell} =require('python-shell'); 

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room })
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

**script.js**

```
const socket = io('/')
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
})

const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
myVideo.muted = true
const peers = {}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: false
}).then(stream => {
  addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)

  myPeer.on('call', call => {
    call.answer(stream)
    const video = document.createElement('video')
    call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
      addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
    })
  })

  socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
    connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
    console.log(userId)
  })
})

socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
  if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
})

myPeer.on('open', id => {
  socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
})

function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

**room.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script>
    const ROOM_ID = "<%= roomId %>"
  </script>
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.2.0/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #video-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    }
    
    video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried injecting the first code segment in your app? I would imagine that the video gets uploaded as some form of byte stream in your javascript code. The trick would involve passing either a processed form, or the raw bytestream as an argument to your python script for processing. Perhaps this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215648/how-to-pass-recorded-video-data-from-javascript-to-python link might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried adding the first code segment, but the issue is I cannot have a "require" call in script.js, so I would need to use something like browserify to make it work, yet when I tried that it wouldn't work